# How do I configure an NFS server to accept all mount requests?

Tags: nfs

Adding 0.0.0.0/32 in /etc/exports does not seem to work. Is there some other configuration option that can be used for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
/filesystem      *
```

You might also try reading `man exports`, which has a set of examples at the bottom from which the above is derived.  You may also wish to note that `0.0.0.0/32` means "*only the IP address 0.0.0.0*".  It is possible that you wwanted `0.0.0.0/0`, which means "*any IP address*", instead, but `*` should do as well.

Comment: This gives tons of warnings

Comment: In my case (Arch Linux) when using "0.0.0.0/0" in share definition and mounting on client, I got an error message "mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.59:/srv/nfs/my_share". But replacing it with "*" in share definition fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

You should also set permissions with the share:

```
     /folder-location *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: `mount_nfs: can't mount /mnt/vault from 192.168.0.108 onto /Users/holms/Vault: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a subnet restriction, then there isn't one. E.g.:

```
/filesystem -sec=sys,ro
```

Will allow anything to mount `ro`. Think carefully about whether you want to allow `rw` or `root` to anything on the network. (You may, but ... well, think about it first)

Comment: it doesn't work